# Python/Selenium: Scraping page for links and scraping links

Tags: html, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am attempting to scrape Fodor's website for all of it's choice restaurants in Amsterdam. I am able to pull the name, price range, and cuisine type from the initial page that the link takes you but I am facing difficulty trying to pull the "href" attribute to get the other pages I want to scrape.

```
#import libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

i = 1
#loop for the multiple pages
for i in range(1, 2, 1):
    i = str(i)
    url = "http://www.fodors.com/world/europe/netherlands/amsterdam/restaurants/fodors-choice/" + i
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.get(url)
    for nameelem in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("h2"):
        print nameelem.text
    for priceandcuisineelem in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("keywords"):
        print priceandcuisineelem.text
    #pull link to scrape other pages
    for restpage in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a"):
        print restpage.get_attribute("href")
```

The problem is that with my current code I pull every possible href on the page. I just want the one with the restaurants I am scraping.